# PHP Array counting null row

Tags: php, arrays, null

Tthe array does count a "false"/null row as a key, even when it returns "null" to the array, it counts as key 0.
How can I make it doesn't count when the value is null?

`[...]
'scripts' => array(
        ($variable ? $object->dostuff(...) : null),
[...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it through `array_filter` first, it'll empty values with a 0 or a null.